# Can't unmarshall XML from exception response body

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

When trying to unmarshal XML error response all elements in object are null.
Using @XmlAnyElement(lax = true) unmarshaller canf ind all the tags, but they are still null.
This is happening on a catch block, using RestTemplate. When the response is 200 using the same approach works for unmarshalling the response body.

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<problem xmlns="urn:ietf:rfc:7807">
    <type>https://foo.bar</type>
    <title>Foo</title>
    <status>400</status>
    <detail>FooBar</detail>
</problem>
```

my class:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "problem", namespace = "urn:ietf:rfc:7807")
public class ErroDict {

    @XmlElement(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @XmlElement(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @XmlElement(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    private List<String> tags;
}
```

code:

```
HttpStatus status = null
...try block...
catch (final HttpClientErrorException e) {
status = e.getStatusCode();
if(status != null && status == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) {
  jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ErroDict.class);
  Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
  jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
  ErroDict erro = (ErroDict) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(e.getResponseBodyAsString()));
```

this gives me null on all elements, and the List also contains all three elements with null values

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution I found was:
Put the class ErrorDict in a package with just it.
In the package I created the package-info.java class and put

`@XmlSchema (namespace = "urn: ietf: rfc: 7807", elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)`

Remove the namespace from the class ErroDict!